# Solving an Initial-Value Problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

I'm unable to fully understand how to solve differential equations systematically. I don't know when to impose a condition of discontinuity and what exactly the conditions of the solution to an IVP problem are.

Alright, the problem consists of four parts:

> (a) Verify that $ y^2-2y = x^2-x+c $ is an implicit solution for the
>   differential equation $$ (2y-2)y'=2x-1 $$
>
> (b) Find a member of the one-parameter family in part(a) that
>   satisfies $y(0)=1$
>
> (c) Use your result in part(b) to find an explicit *function*
>   $y=\phi(x)$ that satisfies $y(0)=1$ and give the domain of $\phi(x)$.
>
> (d) Is $y=\phi(x)$ a solution of the initial-value problem? If so,
>   give its interval I of definition; if not, explain.

What I have tried:

(a) This part is straightforward, just differentiate $ y^2-2y = x^2-x+c $.

(b) Setting $x=0$ and $y=1$ gives $c=1$, thus the solution is $y^2-2y = x^2-x+1$. But I was just wondering why can $y$ be 1? Because when I move $y^2-2y$ to the right I have
$$ y'=\frac{2x-1}{2y-2} $$
which is not defined when $y=1$. I think there must be a misconception.(?)

(c) Okay, I suppose there are solutions that satisfy $y(0)=1$ (or pass through a point $(0,1)$). (Do they really exist?) Now solving $y^2-2y = x^2-x+1$ we get
$$y=1+ \sqrt{x(x-1)}, y=1- \sqrt{x(x-1)}$$
and the domain for both explicit functions is $(-\infty,0)$ and $(1,\infty)$ .

(d) A solution to the initial-value problem has to be differentiable and the interval of definition has to contain the initial point. So, **do I understand correctly that each $\phi(x)$ in part(c) is not a solution of the initial-value problem** because it isn't differentiable and doesn't even pass the point $(0,1)$?
But, still, are they solutions of the differential equation?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Answer to (b): y(0)=1 is not incompatible with $y'(0)=\infty$. You can have infinite slope at x=0, which immediately bends over to finite slope at x>0, like in $y=\sqrt{x}$.

Comment: In (c) there must be an error under one of the roots, otherwise both functions have the same domain.

Comment: What kind of an error do you mean? I think both functions pass through the point (0,1), I suppose?

Comment: There is a typo in the wording of the question. If you differentiate $y^2-2y=x^2-x+c$ you get $(2y-2)y'=2x-1$ which is not what you wrote : $(2y-y)y'=2x-1$.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I will edit that in a minute. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(b) - First things first, the fact that y'(1) is not defined, tells you that y is not differentiable at x=1, and little more. The second comment is that when you devide by (2y - 2) you are tacitly assuming that $y \neq 1$.

(c)  This might just me but isn't the domain of 
$$ y = 1 + \sqrt{x(x - 1)}$$ equal to $( -\infty, 0] \cup [1, \infty) $
which has 0 as a boundary point.

(d) The solutions pass through the point, but are differentiable only in the interior of the function domains. I am a little rusty here, but I seem to recall that only Lipshitz continuity was necessary for existence and uniqueness of a solution...

Comment: I was just wondering that..shouldn't it be (-\infty,0) and (1,\infty)? Because at the boundary the function is not differentiable and therefore y' is not defined?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but the function $y = 1 + \sqrt{x(x - 1)}$ has the given domain where it is real, so y is defined there...

Comment: Aha, I see. The domain you meant is the domain of the function. And, are you saying that, if the function is to be a solution to the DE, it has to be differentiable--which it is only in the interior of the function domains?

Comment: I think this is it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem

Comment: Alright alright.. I think I will have to read about this more

Comment: The function is (uniformly) Lipschitz ;) if it satisfies $ |y(x_1) - y(x_2)| < K | x_1 - x_2 |$ for some constant K. Here K should be independent of choice of  $x_1, x_2$. Though the link claims uniform Lipschitz continuity (LC) on its entire domain is required, I thing you could get away with only locally (uniform) LC near the transitions of the functions. After which, they are differentiable..